# So, "might have been sleeping" (Modal perfect continuous) corresponds to past continuous, present perfect continuous or past perfect continuous?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs, modality

["**Modal + have + PP**" refers to the past](http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/courses/elc/studyzone/410/grammar/410-modals-in-the-past.htm)

But it is quite ambiguous!!

What does "*the past*" mean?

Simple Past, Present perfect, Past perfect all refers to the past.

So the question is:

Does **Modal + have + PP**" refer to Simple Past, Present perfect, or Past perfect?

Similarly,

Does **Modal + have + been + Verb-ing**" refer to Past Continuous, Present perfect continuous, or Past perfect continuous?

Ok, let say, now is 3 pm. At 2 pm (1 hour earlier) you walked by a baby room & you didn't hear any noise.

Now, you say this to your friend:
*The baby might have been sleeping.*

Does that sentence mean:

"*It is possible that the baby was sleeping*"

OR

"*It is possible that the baby has been sleeping* (ie unfinished action & the baby is still sleeping now)"

OR

"*It is possible that the baby had been sleeping* (ie the baby had been sleeping possibly for 30 minutes, but now she is awake)"

But, if you says "*The baby might have been sleeping by the time I was home yesterday*", we can be sure that means "*It is possible that the baby was sleeping by the time I was home yesterday*"

if you says "*The baby might have been sleeping for 1 hour*" (Now is 3pm, & you walked by the baby room at 2pm), we can be sure that means "*It is possible that the baby has been sleeping for 1 hour* (he is still sleeping now, unfinished action)"

if you says "*The baby might have been sleeping for 30 minutes*" (Now is 3pm, & you walked by the baby room at 2pm), we can be sure that means "*It is possible that the baby had been sleeping for 30 minutes* (an action happened in the past and had progressed continuously to another point in the past)"

So, "**might have been sleeping**" (Modal perfect continuous) corresponds to **past continuous, present perfect continuous or past perfect continuous**?

**Note:** *could you include a referenced source in your answers because I need some evidence while teaching students?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I can find the answer in [here](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=qEDKAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT48&lpg=PT48&dq=%22may%20have%20been%20working%20since%22&source=bl&ots=FNcGiVhZyo&sig=RPbXFgZ2WFQtdIZmKy1D9c8tIPA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi51OTF7u3RAhVCKpQKHWkVAbIQ6AEIFzAA#v=onepage&q=%22may%20have%20been%20working%20since%22&f=false)

[image]